# What is the tool to View all exchange MAPI folders?

Tags: exchange-server, mapi

I'm doing some exchange web services development.

As part of the app, I'm creating a hidden folder in the user's exchange mailbox.  I remember reading somewhere that there is a tool that lets you browse *all* your exchange folders... kind of like outlook, but more dev-focused.

I can't seem to google the answer.  Can anyone point me to it?

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 2):

Funny how asking a question gets you to google the right answer:

Here's the tool - [MFC Mapi](http://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/)

Comment: You might also want to take a look at OutlookSpy - http://www.dimastr.com/outspy.It works with both MAPI and Outlook Object Model objects.